# Is Lie Bracket closely related to differentiation?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

This property of Lie bracket attracts me a lot.
$$
[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B.
$$
It looks similar to the product rule of differentiation
$$
(uv)'=u'v+v'u 
$$
The product rule can be used to define the derivative on real and complex manifolds. So I think Lie brackets can define  derivatives as well. However, I struggle to find a detailed definition of  derivative via Lie bracket. That $C$ is quite annoying. I need some reference to learn this definition.

And why $G'=[G,G]$ is called the  derived subgroup of $G$?

Comment: As far as I know, the derived subgroup of a group has nothing to do with differentiation. It's a notion of group theory, which is the smallest normal subgroup $H\subset G$ such that $G/H$ is an abelian group.

Comment: If you write $ad_C$ for the map $X \mapsto [X,C]$ your property just tell you that $ad_C(AB) = A ad_C(B) + ad_C(A)B$ and this is exactly the product rule.

Comment: What does "I think Lie brackers can define derivatives" mean? What exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

It is a derivative of sorts: [lie bracket of vector fields](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields).

Answer (score 1):

On the level of linear Lie algebras, the bracket is given by
$$
[A,B]=AB-BA,
$$
for linear operators $A,B$ in ${\rm End}(V)$. Then we have
$$
[AB,C]=ABC-CAB=A(BC-CB)+(AC-CA)B=A[B,C]+[A,C]B.
$$

Comment: Could you explain why Lie bracket is some sort of diverate?

Comment: Because a Lie algebra is a sort of derivative of  a Lie group. The adjoint operators $ad(x)$ with $ad(x)y=[x,y]$ are *derivations*, satisfying the Leibniz Rule. So, for $d=ad(x)$ we have $d(a.b)=a.d(b)+d(a).b$.